# I'm trying to build a new react.js project and have a compile error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, syntax-error, babeljs

I'm setting up new react project and I try to compile webpack and had syntax error. In my guesses it is due to package.json and webpack.config.js problem

this is my pacakage.json code

```
{
  "name": "blog_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"

  }
}
```

and here is my webpack.config.js code

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'none',
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js'
    },
    watch: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.js'
        ]
    }
}
```

and index.js code I trying to compile and show some div tag on a webbrowser

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class RootEl extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <div><h1>This is JSX!</h1></div>;
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<RootEl />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

and when I try to compile this code and then webpack shows me error message

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\blog\blog\static\src\index.js: Unexpected token (7:15)

   5 |
   6 |     render() {
>  7 |         return <div>This is XML!</div>;
     |                ^
   8 |     }
   9 |
  10 | }
```

Comment: Can you show the babel config file?

Comment: are you try return (<div></div>);  ??

Comment: I didn't have a babel config file and I'm following this video tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx3ChaYA0Gw

Comment: I know this may seem like a stupid question...but you don't have `react` or `react-dom` in your dependencies in your `package.json`?

Comment: sorry I missed npm installl react react dom  now I installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX (like `<div>` inside javascript) is not a valid javascript syntax. You need babel to transpile those JSX into a valid javascript. To do it, you need to tell babel HOW to transpile those.

You should install `@babel/preset-react` and set babel up so it will use that preset.

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                      presets: [
                        ['@babel/preset-react'],
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

Presets are basically just a set of rules that babel can refer to when trying to transpile codes.